# PHP Security test gives me critical Reflected XSS warning for GetHTMLValueString, how can i fix?

Tags: php, web, xss, php-7

[image]

PHP Security test gives me critical Reflected XSS warning for GetHTMLValueString, how can i fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try convert value to [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

```
<?php $depo_gin = '<a>1</a>'; ?>
<td>...</td><td><?php echo htmlentities( GetHTMLValueString($depo_gin) ); ?></td>
```

OR

```
<?php $depo_gin = '<a>1</a>'; ?>
<td>...</td><td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( GetHTMLValueString($depo_gin) ); ?></td>
```

Result in HTML:

```
<td>...</td><td>&lt;a&gt;1&lt;/a&gt;</td>
```

Docs:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

**If you need only value from html content**

Try use function `strip_tags`

```
<?php 

var_dump(
  strip_tags('<a>1</a>')
); # result: 1
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags